# Accessing sub-array data from theme_field__custom_content_type($variables)

Tags: theming

This is a mix of a PHP and a Drupal question.

I created a custom function...

```
theme_field__custom_content_type($variables)
```

I have the DEVEL module installed and have been using it profusely. I'm trying to modify the layout/look of a custom content through a childtheme I'm developing. I'm running into an issues that is leaving me scratching my head.

I have a custom content type [netrunner_card] and it has several fields that are taxonomy references. One field in particular is [field_card_subtype]. A card can have multiple subtypes... "Location," "Seedy," "Cloud," etc. What I want to do is to take those subtypes and place them next to another field like so:

```
field_card_type : field_card_subtype[0] - field_card_subtype[1] - etc
```

So that you would see output like:

Operation : Location - Seedy

ICE : AP - Trap

etc.

What I am doing is the following...
Yes, I am creating custom variables for this as it helps to collect everything in an easy to use package.

```
$blinksFieldName = $variables['element']['#field_name'];
switch( $blinksFieldName )
{
    case 'field_unique_card':
        $variables['card_is_unique'] = $variables['element']['#items'][0]['value'];
        break;
    case 'field_card_subtype':
        $variables['card_subtype_list'] = implode( " - ", $variables['element']['#items']);
        break;
    ...
}
```

When I kpr( $variables['card_subtype_list'] ) I get a string of the word 'Array'. I think that's because the breakdown of the variable in question is more like:

```
$variables['element']['#items'][0]['#title']
```

I'm very confused how you reach that level of the array when one of the placeholders is the array index... I had thought to do a for-next but I can't figure out how I would word it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the code you are showing for the `theme_field()` theme function? If that is the case, `$variables` should not contain `$variables['element']`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I get what you're doing...you won't be able to straight implode the items array if it's a sequential set that you're using to build up a list of key/value pairs...

There are probably a few different ways to do that loop, I'd try something like this:

```
$keys = $values = array();
$count = 1;
foreach ($variables['element']['#items'] as $item) {
  if ($count++ % 2 == 1) {
    $keys[] = $item['#title'];
  }
  else {
    $values[] = $item['#title'];
  }
}

$output = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
  $output .= $keys[$i] . ' - ' . $values[$i] . '<br />';
}
$variables['card_subtype_list'] = $output;
```

Hopefully someone will propose a better solution, that's not exactly elegant. Apologies if I've misunderstood.

Comment: the third line up from the bottom has $values[$] and I'm hitting errors. I wanted to just test your idea and see if it helped me find this 'better solution' of which you speak... but I keep getting errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: It was a typo sorry, should have been `$values[$i]`. That probably won't do the whole thing, but the logic to get the items into key/value pairs is there

Comment: I don't get how that loop can obtain `$variables['element']['#items'][$index]['#title']` values.

Comment: Ok... a couple things @Clive. #1) I was getting an Undefined index #title. So I KPR'd and see that $variables['element']['#title'] doesn't exist. I get a tid (String) and a taxonomy_term (Object), but that's all. So I dug around and I see that THIS get's to what I am looking for...

    $variables['element'][0]['#title']

Comment: Second thing @Clive.
What does the following line do: 


    $count++ % 2 == 1


My php skills are rusty (at best)...

Comment: It's the same as in C++..._Increment the counter after the current line has been processed. If the remainder of the division between $count and 2 is "1", do this, otherwise do that._. It's just a simple way to process the array items alternately. You probably want to be looping over `$variables['element']` in that case...

Comment: Well, now it dawns on me that there is a glitch in this process. I need those subtypes to be links. Just like they would be if they were output in the manner that they usually are... ugh. I think this just got a lot more complicated.

Comment: Have a think about the general approach you're using. You're using a sequential list to store key/value pairs...that will never work out very well as your data is weakly structured, and you're fighting to re-format it into something it was never meant to be. Have you come across the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module before? It would fit your use case a bit better

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8897/discussion-between-randomblink-and-clive)

Comment: Sorry am in the office at the moment, can't chat...

Comment: No worries. I'm just trying to 'avoid extended discussions in comments.' Can I just type there and wait to get responses for later?

Answer (score 0):

What I did to make this work is as follows.
Inside template.php, in the following function:

```
function blinks_responsive_field__netrunner_card($variables)
```

I checked the $delta in the foreach for which subtype I was on.

```
$subTypeSpacer = '';
if( $blinksFieldName == 'field_card_subtype' ){ if( $delta > 0 ){ $subTypeSpacer = ' - '; } }
```

So if we were on subtype #0 (the first one) then don't add the hyphen. Otherwise add it. Then to insert the subTypeSpacer into our output I did the following:

```
$output .= '<div class="' . $classes . '"' . $variables['item_attributes'][$delta] . '>' . $subTypeSpacer . drupal_render($item) . '</div>';
```

This put everything together in our $variables. Now we have to call them.
So we move ahead to node--netrunner-card--Operation--full.tpl.php

In here, we are custom styling the output for an Operation card. Jump down to where render( $content ) used to go, and we see this:

```
<div class="field-card-type"><?php print render( $content['field_card_type']); ?> : <?php print render( $content['field_card_subtype'] ); ?></div>
```

So, now we have all of the elements together, but they sure don't look pretty. These divs are treated like block elements, so they each get their own line. Not acceptable. So let's jump to style.css and do this...

```
div.field-card-type div
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Done.

If you'd like to see a sample here is what it looks like: [A single operation card with the card subtypes styled like desired.](http://netrunner.randomblink.com/node/196)